# CountDownTimer in Android

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I am implementing countdown timer, but its not working for me. Below is the code.

```
package FinalProj.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

public class iFallApp extends Activity{
    public TextView textView1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        //textview.setText("This is the iFall tab");
       // setContentView()
        setContentView(R.layout.ifallapp);

        textView1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        MyCount counter = new MyCount(5000,1000);
        counter.start();


    }

    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }

        iFallApp app1 = new iFallApp();

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            textView1.setText("done");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            textView1.setText((int) (millisUntilFinished/1000));

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How exactly is it misbehaving?

Comment: After launching the application stops... there is some problem with onTick method... if I comment it out then the application works fine...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's this line causing the problem;

```
textView1.setText((int) (millisUntilFinished/1000));
```

What you do, is set a resource id for textView1, while what you are looking for is something like;

```
textView1.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1000));
```

Also line;

```
        iFallApp app1 = new iFallApp();
```

Is rather suspicious. Remove it just in case before you end up using it accidentally. You have your iFallApp created by Android framework already, and you can pass it using `this`instead if needed.

Answer (score 1):

A heads up for any other developers following this as an example, but have abstracted their Timer into its own toplevel class. Passing a TextView into the CountDownTimer instance will result in a memory leak if you don't carefully clean up the references. This will be apparent after rotating the screen a half a dozen times, your app will crash with an OutOfMemoryError as mine did.

Add a method to your CountDownTimer like this, and call it whenever onDestroy()/onDestroyView() in the owning Activity/Fragment is called.

```
public void safeCancel() {
   this.textView1 = null;
   super.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you should be able to look at the `adb logcat` output to determine what's going wrong.

Off the top of my head I'd say that the `textView1` variable is not being properly set and is null.

Also, I would start the countdown timer in the `onResume()` function, not the `onCreate()` function.